Attempting to POST to Google Form with login
EDIT: The extra inputs aside from email, token, and entry elements are not needed. Removing the dlut, submissionTimestamp, hud, fvv, partialResponse, and fbzx allows the request to successfully submit.
I saved cookies from when I manually logged into a google account, and I need them for a form that requires the user to be logged in.
The form is pretty simple. It asks for the users information and a few random questions. I can easily get the form elements and create the data like so:
enterData = {
   "emailAddress":"emailhere@gmail.com",
   "dlut":"1734495396",
   "submissionTimestamp":"1734503245",
   "entry.466815253_sentinel":"",
   "token":"redacted",
   "hud":"true",
   "fvv":"1",
   "partialResponse":"[null,null,\"-2993399899787926559\"]",
   "pageHistory":"0",
   "fbzx":"-2993399899787926559",
   "entry.2006548712":"answer1",
   "entry.526914826":"answer2",
   "entry.481670044":"answer3",
   "entry.114368998":"answer4",
   "entry.346692381":"123 main st",
   "entry.93217058":"",
   "entry.657953517":"Chesterfield",
   "entry.1938294066":"MO",
   "entry.1075043656":"63017-5428",
   "entry.466815253":"11"
}

These are the exact inputs required for Google Forms, and this is the URL to post to:
https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSeQTjQNyWj1RidzWyM7qYyXv0QyXShg5WfawQIAbn3wgPqAcg/formResponse
And this is the code being used to post it:
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSeQTjQNyWj1RidzWyM7qYyXv0QyXShg5WfawQIAbn3wgPqAcg/formResponse'
    resp = session.post(url=url, data=enterData)

The request receives a 200 status code so theres no issues with authentication, but it doesn't actually post to the form. The HTML response shows that the form elements are filled in, but they're not actually being sent for some reason. I can't figure out why it would be filling in the form but not actually sending it. Any help would be appreciated.

I think you should not use your cookies like this, this is not secure at all. I recommend you to use the Google lib :
pip install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2

Using OAuth 2.0 is the proper way to authenticate with Google services, and it ensures both security and reliability for your application.

It’s not an issue of security because I own both the email and the form. I just want it to post correctly, I’ve tried some things but nothing has worked so far.
